# Xcode / Fastlane - setting up separate bundle identifiers

Tags: ios, xcode, fastlane

I have an iOS application which we deploy to Testflight and to the App Store using Fastlane and Match.

We basically have a version of our app that points to our Staging servers, and one that points to Production, however they use the same bundle identifier.  So we have to uninstall one to install the other on a given device.

How can I setup my project so I can install both apps side-by-side?  I'm also looking to add a 3rd "beta" version, which will be the pre-release version that our testflighers can use.

I know that each of these need their own bundle identifiers, provisioning profiles, certificates and push certificates, but I'm not quite sure if I should be creating new Targets in XCode, or perhaps Schemes?

Comment: On the fastlane side this will not be a problem at all, no matter how you decide to structure it inside Xcode. Several of the Fastlane setup examples on https://github.com/fastlane/examples use different bundle identifiers. On obvious example: https://github.com/fastlane/examples/blob/master/Wikipedia/Appfile

Comment: What was your resolution in the end? As I see it TestFlight requires the same bundle id as the app store version and so you can't have the beta and app store versions installed side by side?